# C# UITypeEditor: How to show CustomDialog directly under GridItem?

Tags: c#

I have created a custom UITypeEditor to show a Form and edit the values in it.

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
{
    DialogResult result = dropDownForm.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Get the Selected Entry
        return dropDownForm.Value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

That is fine and simple but now I want to position that form directly under the GridItem of the PropertyGrid.

dropDownForm.Location = ???

This would do the trick but where do I get the right position for the form.

First approach:

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
{
    if (context != null && provider != null)
    {
        // Uses the IWindowsFormsEditorService to display a 
        // drop-down UI in the Properties window:
        editorService = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;

        if (editorService != null)
        {
            // Add Values to the list control
            PopulateListBox(context, value);

            // Set to false before showing the control
            escPressed = false;

            // Attach the ListBox to the DropDown Control
            editorService.DropDownControl(listDropDown);

            // User pressed the ESC key --> Return the Old Value
            if (!escPressed)
            {
                // Get the Selected Entry
                ListBoxEntry entry = ListBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxEntry;

                // If an Object is Selected and valid --> Return it
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    return entry.value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}

public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
}
```

I have added that to clarify the problem. In this situation my listbox height grows with every entry. If I add only a small amount everything is fine, the dropdown shows my listbox as it should be.
[See right dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AqA0.png)

When I add many entries than the following problem occurs: The dropdown is shown above the GridItem and is partially outside of the screen.
[See wrong dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zjAG.png)

So here I would solve the problem the same way. When I am able to get the position of the griditem in that function I could calculate the max height for the list and everything is fine.

thx for the help

Comment: Use UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown instead.  The Anchor property editor is a good example.  Look at the .NET AnchorEditor class with a good decompiler.

Comment: True, but the AnchorEditor has a fixed size and my form grows when more data is added to it, which means it is possible that it is bigger than the screen, and then the dropdown is position wrong and it moved outside of the screen. I don't know how to overcome that problem else than calculate the maximum size of my form and therefore I need the position of the GridItem.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, it will become unusable when the Properties window is close to the edge of the screen.

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify the problem and add some screenshots to show it better.